# Android LinearLayout background Image

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm having a problem with my view if I try to display an image as background, it took the whole space and the second child of linear layout (2 RelativeLayout that appears next to each other) does not appear into view.

How can I set image as background keeping other layout elements above it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/globe"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>


      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a bit late, but my problem was solved with the following code.

Used the `ImageView` to set my background image and then displayed the linear layout over it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/my_msg"
        android:src="@drawable/my_super_bg_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/top_style"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/today"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="some text here"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

If some one needs to know more, I will update the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: iv should not have match parent and for example fitxy for cases ll layout is bigger as image drawable bg ?

Comment: In my case I also needed to add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` for ImageView

Answer (score 5):

Use `android:background` in your `LinearLayout`

Comment: I find this answer can still be helpful for those who have a specific resolution in mind and can do a bit of image editing

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `android:background` property instead having an `ImageView`.

Comment: As mentioned at other place, when using this attribute the image is either stretched and squeezed to fit the device screen. I want the image to be centered and not stretched and squeezed.